Is it possible to reliably buffer outgoing POST requests from an offline React PWA?
Is there any way to have a service worker intercept and buffer POST requests from my React components and delivery them when network connectivity allows?
I'm planning on using next-pwa to support offline operation of an app which needs the user to enter equipment readings in an area of poor network connectivity. Reliable delivery of collected data is vital and I can't simply provide a 'try again later' message as disconnected periods may be lengthy.
I suppose what I'm thinking of is a PWA version of an outgoing message queue such as ActiveMQ or MSMQ.

"Is it possible/Is there any way…?": Yes, but asking for a complete implementation of such functionality is out of scope for a single Stack Overflow question. (See [ask] for more info.) Can you [edit] the question to include a [mre] of the code you wrote, and explain where you think the problem occurs or at which specific step you are stuck?

Hi. Thanks for having a think about this but I wasn't asking for a complete, or even partial implementation. I was asking is there a way. Perhaps the answer might be there is no native support for this so it would be a case of writing bespoke code using persistent storage of some kind. However, if there were either native support for this or some library its worth knowing before I go ahead and write it myself. Ta.

^ Asking for recommendations for off-site/third-party libraries/software is not on-topic for Stack Overflow — so if you aren't seeking an implementation, and also not simply "Yes, this is possible" — then what kind of answer do you hope to solicit? Can you [edit] the question to clarify?

Well precisely the answer that was given. Its perfect.

You could try using TanStackQuery, which seems to support automatically retrying mutations when offline.
You can also persist mutations, which could be helpful for supporting long offline intervals
Disclaimer: I have used TanStack Query, but I never used it for implementing offline mutations - I just found it in the docs

Perfect, thank you Steffen. Persistent mutations work great.
